# Tikz and lines with the Q letter

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix, tikz-pic

I do have a tex, that always show me a twolines, in a tikzfigure when letter Q is in the line. Let me share the TEX with you

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

%\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes, style={font=\ttfamily}, nodes={minimum width=1.6cm,minimum 
 height=1.6cm, draw,thin},draw, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 { 
 D  &G  &W  &P  &V  &W  &N  &J  &A  &J  &V  &O\\  
 I  &E  &R  &E  &I  &K  &E  &Y  &M  &U  &N  &O\\  
 P  &L  &E  &N  &G  &B  &C  &R  &W  &J  &R  &A\\  
 K  &I  &C  &T  &O  &G  &F  &E  &B  &S  &O  &E\\  
 Y  &P  &T  &A  &W  &N  &O  &F  &Q  &X  &O  &U\\  
 C  &S  &A  &G  &C  &U  &A  &D  &R  &A  &D  &O\\  
 I  &E  &N  &O  &T  &J  &N  &N  &D  &N  &B  &K\\  
 R  &L  &G  &N  &Z  &O  &N  &C  &B  &E  &U  &N\\  
 C  &D  &U  &O  &P  &M  &Z  &Y  &X  &J  &D  &W\\  
 U  &A  &L  &U  &A  &B  &F  &E  &L  &O  &R  &T\\  
 L  &Q  &O  &T  &R  &I  &A  &N  &G  &U  &L  &O\\  
 O  &A  &U  &U  &N  &B  &I  &V  &B  &D  &U  &H\\  
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}

A buscar: 
\begin{itemize}
\item PENTAGONO
\item CUADRADO
\item CIRCULO
\item TRIANGULO
\item ELIPSE
\item RECTANGULO
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

When I do that. Always the lines with Q in the pdf show double lines. I browse around but have no hints on how to solve it.

There is a figure of the result in that line :

[image: Near to the Q letter]

Any help is really appreciated it.

JP

Comment: It is the descender in `Q` which is the issue.  Replace `Q` with `\smash{Q}\vphantom{X}` and problem goes away.

Answer (score 7):

You need to define nodes anchors, for example `anchor=center`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, 
             nodes = {draw,thin, minimum size=1.6cm, anchor=center},
             draw, 
             row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 {
 D  &G  &W  &P  &V  &W  &N  &J  &A  &J  &V  &O\\
 I  &E  &R  &E  &I  &K  &E  &Y  &M  &U  &N  &O\\
 P  &L  &E  &N  &G  &B  &C  &R  &W  &J  &R  &A\\
 K  &I  &C  &T  &O  &G  &F  &E  &B  &S  &O  &E\\
 Y  &P  &T  &A  &W  &N  &O  &F  &Q  &X  &O  &U\\
 C  &S  &A  &G  &C  &U  &A  &D  &R  &A  &D  &O\\
 I  &E  &N  &O  &T  &J  &N  &N  &D  &N  &B  &K\\
 R  &L  &G  &N  &Z  &O  &N  &C  &B  &E  &U  &N\\
 C  &D  &U  &O  &P  &M  &Z  &Y  &X  &J  &D  &W\\
 U  &A  &L  &U  &A  &B  &F  &E  &L  &O  &R  &T\\
 L  &Q  &O  &T  &R  &I  &A  &N  &G  &U  &L  &O\\
 O  &A  &U  &U  &N  &B  &I  &V  &B  &D  &U  &H\\
 };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it works. Is it better to use an anchor that the option of text depth=0pt?

Answer (score 6):

As my comment indicated, the issue is the `Q` has depth that the other capital letters lack.  To resolve this, you can set `text depth=0pt`.  With such an approach, the baselines of the letters are uniformly preserved.

While not needed for this MWE, Schroedinger's cat points out that  `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` offers other similar options to `text depth` that may be useful in comparable problems.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

%\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes, style={font=\ttfamily}, nodes={minimum width=1.6cm,minimum 
 height=1.6cm, text depth=0pt, draw,thin},draw, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 { 
 D  &G  &W  &P  &V  &W  &N  &J  &A  &J  &V  &O\\  
 I  &E  &R  &E  &I  &K  &E  &Y  &M  &U  &N  &O\\  
 P  &L  &E  &N  &G  &B  &C  &R  &W  &J  &R  &A\\  
 K  &I  &C  &T  &O  &G  &F  &E  &B  &S  &O  &E\\  
 Y  &P  &T  &A  &W  &N  &O  &F  &Q  &X  &O  &U\\  
 C  &S  &A  &G  &C  &U  &A  &D  &R  &A  &D  &O\\  
 I  &E  &N  &O  &T  &J  &N  &N  &D  &N  &B  &K\\  
 R  &L  &G  &N  &Z  &O  &N  &C  &B  &E  &U  &N\\  
 C  &D  &U  &O  &P  &M  &Z  &Y  &X  &J  &D  &W\\  
 U  &A  &L  &U  &A  &B  &F  &E  &L  &O  &R  &T\\  
 L  &Q  &O  &T  &R  &I  &A  &N  &G  &U  &L  &O\\  
 O  &A  &U  &U  &N  &B  &I  &V  &B  &D  &U  &H\\  
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}

A buscar: 
\begin{itemize}
\item PENTAGONO
\item CUADRADO
\item CIRCULO
\item TRIANGULO
\item ELIPSE
\item RECTANGULO
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it also works. Is it better to use a text depth that an anchor?

Comment: @user111375 It's your preference, I would think.

Comment: @user111375 `text depth` is better, just look at the vertical position of `Q` in the other answer. This key does not require the `positioning` library, though. You should set the `text depth`, the `text height` and the anchor.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for the clarification on library.  I will edit.

Comment: The positioning library is in principle the right tool to address such problems, it has keys like `base right` and so on which are useful for aligning the baselines of characters/texts. So it is useful to mention it.